# Find segmentation fault while passing map to function C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, segmentation-fault

I can't find the segmentation fault which is occuring on the line where I am calling `calculate_grundy` in `main`. Please help.

I have also added a screenshot of my debugger while debugging the code.

This is a question of a running contest so please don't answer logic problems instead of helping me in finding the segmentation fault.

I am passing the `dp` map for storing the subproblems, as done in dynamic programming.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;

ll calculate_mex(unordered_set<ll> Set)
{
    ll mex = 0;
    while(Set.find(mex)!=Set.end())
    {
        mex++;
    }
    return mex;
}

ll calculate_grundy(ll n,ll m,map<pair<ll,ll>,ll> &dp)
{
    auto it = dp.find(make_pair(n,m));
    if(it!=dp.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        ll ans;
        ll greater = max(n,m);
        ll smaller = min(n,m);
        if(n==m || m==0 || n==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(n==1 || m==1)
        {
            return n==1?m:n;
        }
        unordered_set<ll> Set;
        ll limit = greater%smaller;
        for(ll i=1;i<=limit;i++)
        {
            ll mult = smaller*i;
            Set.insert(calculate_grundy(greater-mult,smaller,dp));
        }
        ans = calculate_mex(Set);
        dp.insert(make_pair(make_pair(n,m),ans));
        return ans;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        map<pair<ll,ll>,ll> dp;
        if(calculate_grundy(n,m,dp)==0)
        {
            cout<<"Ari"<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Rich"<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Looks like infinite recursion](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdee841c21874725).

Comment: can you please suggest a suitable base condition or a place where it doesnt terminate but it should?

Comment: Your first 3 lines of code are all bad in different ways. Please do not use the style of coding used in "code competitions" to actually write good code.

Comment: sorry about namespace i know it should not be used.This is only for contests.

Comment: I cannot. I have no clue what you are trying to do and you don't want help with the logic. I suggest you put `std::cout << "Calling calculate_grundy with " << greater-mult << ", " << smaller << '\n';` before `Set.insert(calculate_grundy(greater-mult,smaller,dp));` and see if the output is what you expect. You don't change `dp` before the recursion, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: the problem seems to be in the greater smaller it doesnt seem to change and the values go into negative

Comment: but i have made greater as max already

Comment: Without knowing exactly what is the logic, `limit = greater%smaller` seems to be the source of the problem, because it lets `greater-mult` go into negative. Are you sure it wasn't supposed to be `limit = greater/smaller` instead?

Comment: Yeah I identified the problem it's the % it should be / I made a huge mistake.Thanks everybody for their help.